# Python: pip: how to change color of pip errormessages?

Tags: python, colors, pip, windows-console

Using pip in a console window under windows 7 I can barely see the text of the errormessages.

[image]

Is there any chance to tell pip to use another color? This dark red on top of black is a bad choice. 
My workaround currently is to copy the text into an editor and read it there but this is not a nice solution.

Comment: Well, you can try changing the color scheme of the windows cmd (by right clicking on the title bar and going to properties), to change background color to white

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that it is that easy to change the command prompt color. It did not change the old error messages that was already displayed but new messages are printed dark red on white now, thanks alot.

Answer (score 6):

There is a "--no-color" command line option: 
https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip/#general-options